# Does xcode support tab controls?

Tags: ios, ipad, cocoa-touch

I am developing a dashboard system which I need to split the app's screen into 4 blocks. Each block needs to have a page/tab control with different tabs such as day, month, week, etc

Is this not supported in xcode?  I can only see references to a tab control where the tabs are at the bottom of the app's screen

Comment: By "in Xcode", do you mean the Cocoa Touch API?

Comment: Yes I will be using monotouch so will have access to all the native controls

Comment: Well I think I mean cocoa touch Api not too sure as am new to this

Comment: Note that Xcode is just the IDE.

Comment: @Paul Fine, I edited the tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you please try one of the control here in http://www.cocoacontrols.com/tags/tab?

Comment: Thanks looks like I could use the browser tab view. I can't test it yet but I think it will be fine but I need to see how I can get 4 of them on a screen on the iPad

Answer (score 0):

I strongly recommend sticking with the tabs at the bottom. If you want them at the top you will have to implement your own solution or find one by someone else.

Comment: I will be having 4 charts visible at once , each chart needs to be in its own page control so that the user can be on, say, month for 2 charts and year for the other 2. The normal tab approach wouldn't allow me to show all 4 charts at the same time